# JavaScript: Looping through an array of booleans

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, boolean

I'm looking to loop through an array of booleans that will change based on what link the user clicks on. First, I initialize them...

```
var boolean1 = false;
var boolean2 = false;
var boolean3 = false;
```

Next, I have Strings that contain the links to a new page...

```
var link1 = "index.html";
var link2 = "someotherpage.html";
var link3 = "somepage.html";
```

Then, I put the values in respective arrays

```
var booleanArray = new Array(3);
booleanArray[0] = boolean1;
booleanArray[1] = boolean1;
booleanArray[2] = boolean1;

var linkArray = new Array(3);
linkArray[0] = link1;
linkArray[1] = link2;
linkArray[2] = link3;
```

Then, I have functions that change the values (The values will be called based one what link the user clicks on)...

```
//onlick...
function changeBoolean1()
{
    boolean1 = true;
}
function changeBoolean2()
{
    boolean2 = true
}
function changeBoolean3() 
{
    boolean3 = true;
}
```

Finally, based on which method was called `onlick`, one of the booleans will be set to `false`. At that point, I want to loop through the array of booleans, and get which one was set to `false`. Based on which one was `false`, it's respective link will open.

```
function getChoice()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < booleanArray.length; i++)
    {
        if(booleanArray[i] == true)
        {
            window.location.href = linkArray[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the method does not get based the

Comment: Why won’t you just use an array literal? `var booleanArray=[false,false,false], linkArray=["index.html", "someotherpage.html", "somepage.html"];` instead of _everything_ before the functions. Isn’t this so much nicer to read and easier to work with?

Comment: why don't you use object property like {"link":'index.html',"status":true}? it will help you easily manage your code and you will don't face your current reference related problems

Comment: Why do you ask "why not" when the answer likely is that OP did not get that far in the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change you onclick functions to update the array instead of the original variables

```
//onlick...
function changeBoolean1() {
    booleanArray[0] = true;
}
function changeBoolean2() {
    booleanArray[1] = true
}
function changeBoolean3() {
    booleanArray[2] = true;
}
```

---

Since Booleans are primitives, what gets stored in the actual array is the values and **not** a reference to your original variable (as you would expect with objects)

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. I've done a lot of work with Java, and the switch to JavaScript is kinda difficult. Nevertheless, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

primitive type variable like string,number are always pass as pass by value.
so you need to set your value explicitly in array or set your boolean property in a object.

Answer (score -1):

```
function changeBool(booleanArray, index){
     booleanArray[index] = true;
}

function getChoice(){
    for(var i = 0; i < booleanArray.length; ++i){
        if(booleanArray[i]){
            window.location.href = linkArray[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe what that code is doing? Just putting a bunch of code without any description is not a good answer